# Inquire variable in other class / activity if it is filled

Tags: java, android, class, variables, methods

I am beginner in Java and Android. I searched yesterday a whole day for a solution. I want to check a variable in second activity if it is filled. Or ask the methode "loadAngebote" if it has a return value. The methode that is executed to get data is:

```
public class loadAngebote extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot>>{

    String data ="";

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> doInBackground(String... params){

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://url/file.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
            ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i =0 ;i <jArray.length(); i++){
                listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
            }

            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
            String[][] matrix = new String[json.length()][6];

            for (int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                matrix[i][0] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("ID"));
                matrix[i][1] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("art_nr"));
                matrix[i][2] = String.valueOf(obj.getDouble("preis"));
                matrix[i][3] = obj.getString("von");
                matrix[i][4] = obj.getString("bis");
                matrix[i][5] = obj.getString("art_link");
            }

            String[] all_ID = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_art_nr = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_preis = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_von = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_bis = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_link = new String[matrix.length];


            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                all_ID[i] = matrix[i][0];
                all_art_nr[i] = matrix[i][1];
                all_preis[i] = matrix[i][2];
                all_von[i] = matrix[i][3];
                all_bis[i] = matrix[i][4];
                all_link[i] = matrix[i][5];
            }

            ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                ArtikelAngebot angebote = new ArtikelAngebot(all_art_nr[i], "Für: " + all_preis[i] + " €","Von: " + all_von[i],"Bis: " + all_bis[i], all_link[i]);
                dataList.add(angebote);
            }

            return dataList;   <--------------------------------------------


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> QueryResult){

        AngeboteListAdapter adapter = new AngeboteListAdapter(AngeboteActivity.this, R.layout.angebote_list_view_adapter, QueryResult);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

I need to check if dataList is filled in an other class of my app:

```
static String getLocationResultTitle(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
    if(?????dataList_is_filled?????){
        String numLocationsReported = "Text1";
        return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :) \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    }else{
        String numLocationsReported = "Text2";
        return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :( \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

    }
```

Comment: you can use libraries like RX Java `http://reactivex.io/` or Event bus `http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/`

Comment: @user8800556 check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Here is your **AngeboteActivity**

```
public class AngeboteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public enum DataHolder {
        INSTANCE;

        private ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> mObjectList;

        public static boolean hasData() {
            return INSTANCE.mObjectList != null;
        }

        public static ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> getData() {
            final ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> retList = INSTANCE.mObjectList;
            INSTANCE.mObjectList = null;
            return retList;
        }

        public static void setData(final ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> objectList) {
            INSTANCE.mObjectList = objectList;
        }
    }

    public class loadAngebote extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot>> {

        String data = "";

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://url/file.php");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                while (line != null) {
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    data = data + line;
                }
                ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
                }

                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
                String[][] matrix = new String[json.length()][6];

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    matrix[i][0] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("ID"));
                    matrix[i][1] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("art_nr"));
                    matrix[i][2] = String.valueOf(obj.getDouble("preis"));
                    matrix[i][3] = obj.getString("von");
                    matrix[i][4] = obj.getString("bis");
                    matrix[i][5] = obj.getString("art_link");
                }

                String[] all_ID = new String[matrix.length];
                String[] all_art_nr = new String[matrix.length];
                String[] all_preis = new String[matrix.length];
                String[] all_von = new String[matrix.length];
                String[] all_bis = new String[matrix.length];
                String[] all_link = new String[matrix.length];


                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                    all_ID[i] = matrix[i][0];
                    all_art_nr[i] = matrix[i][1];
                    all_preis[i] = matrix[i][2];
                    all_von[i] = matrix[i][3];
                    all_bis[i] = matrix[i][4];
                    all_link[i] = matrix[i][5];
                }

                ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                    ArtikelAngebot angebote = new ArtikelAngebot(all_art_nr[i], "Für: " + all_preis[i] + " €", "Von: " + all_von[i], "Bis: " + all_bis[i], all_link[i]);
                    dataList.add(angebote);
                }

                DataHolder.setData(dataList);

                return dataList;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> QueryResult) {

            AngeboteListAdapter adapter = new AngeboteListAdapter(AngeboteActivity.this, R.layout.angebote_list_view_adapter, QueryResult);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

And Here is your **Utils** class

```
public class Utils {
    static String getLocationResultTitle(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
        if (AngeboteActivity.DataHolder.hasData()) {
            //if hasData do your stuff what you want
            String numLocationsReported = "Text1";
            return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :) \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        } else {
            String numLocationsReported = "Text2";
            return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :( \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He dont know the class DataHolder >.< Because getLocationResultTitle is in an other java file.

Comment: @user8800556 i know that..DataHolder is  `enum`..and In First Activity (loadAngebote) class he has to just put that code and assign value to it...and in any other activity user can check easily as per question is asked.

Comment: @user8800556 are you getting it or not?

Comment: @user8800556 have you tried my answer?
Just copy and paste DataHolder in your **loadAngebote** Activity..

Comment: @user8800556 you are doing it wrong way..i think you forget to put DataHolder in your First Activity(loadAngebote)

Comment: i did, sec I poste it

Comment: @user8800556 what is the name of your First Activity??

Comment: First Activity = AngeboteActivity and the other Java class/file is named Utils.java

Comment: watch my updated answer below. dont work on this way

Comment: @user8800556 Yes, i have go through your activity, it is all set in that..
now in for Utils class check my new answer.just make one change and its works like charm.

Comment: Great it works ! Nice way to check variables if they has data or not. Thx you very much for spending your time ! Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**  My Angebote Activity:

```
public class AngeboteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static TextView data;
public static ListView mListView;

private static final String TAG = "AngeboteActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_angebote);

    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    new loadAngebote().execute();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "On Start .....");

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Object Inhalt = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            final Intent intent = new Intent(AngeboteActivity.this, AngeboteRequestInfoActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //Objekt Serialisieren
            bundle.putSerializable("object", (Serializable) Inhalt);
            //Objekt in Intent Extras packen
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            AngeboteActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}



private class QueryResult {
    ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> dataList;
    public QueryResult(ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList ;
    }
}

public enum DataHolder {
    INSTANCE;

    private ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> mObjectList;

    public static boolean hasData() {
        return INSTANCE.mObjectList != null;
    }

    public static void setData(final ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> objectList) {
        INSTANCE.mObjectList = objectList;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> retList = INSTANCE.mObjectList;
        INSTANCE.mObjectList = null;
        return retList;
    }
}


public class loadAngebote extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot>>{

    String data ="";

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> doInBackground(String... params){

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://url/request.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }
            ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i =0 ;i <jArray.length(); i++){
                listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
            }

            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
            String[][] matrix = new String[json.length()][6];


            for (int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                matrix[i][0] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("ID"));
                matrix[i][1] = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("art_nr"));
                matrix[i][2] = String.valueOf(obj.getDouble("preis"));
                matrix[i][3] = obj.getString("von");
                matrix[i][4] = obj.getString("bis");
                matrix[i][5] = obj.getString("art_link");
            }


            String[] all_ID = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_art_nr = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_preis = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_von = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_bis = new String[matrix.length];
            String[] all_link = new String[matrix.length];


            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                all_ID[i] = matrix[i][0];
                all_art_nr[i] = matrix[i][1];
                all_preis[i] = matrix[i][2];
                all_von[i] = matrix[i][3];
                all_bis[i] = matrix[i][4];
                all_link[i] = matrix[i][5];
            }

            ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                ArtikelAngebot angebote = new ArtikelAngebot(all_art_nr[i], "Für: " + all_preis[i] + " €","Von: " + all_von[i],"Bis: " + all_bis[i], all_link[i]);
                dataList.add(angebote);
            }

            DataHolder.setData(dataList);

            return dataList;


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArtikelAngebot> QueryResult){

        AngeboteListAdapter adapter = new AngeboteListAdapter(AngeboteActivity.this, R.layout.angebote_list_view_adapter, QueryResult);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

My Utils.java class

```
public class Utils {

final static String KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_REQUESTED = "location-updates-requested";
final static String KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_RESULT = "location-update-result";

static void setRequestingLocationUpdates(Context context, boolean value) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_REQUESTED, value)
            .apply();
}

static boolean getRequestingLocationUpdates(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getBoolean(KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);
}

/**
 * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
 * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
 */
static void sendNotification(Context context, String notificationDetails) {
    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AngeboteActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra("from_notification", true);

    // Construct a task stack.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(AngeboteActivity.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    // Notification Einstellungen
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
            // to decode the Bitmap.
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle("Ihre Apotheke vor Ort")
            .setContentText(notificationDetails)
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Issue the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}


/**
 * Returns the title for reporting about a list of {@link Location} objects.
 *
 * @param context The {@link Context}.
 */
static String getLocationResultTitle(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
    if (AngeboteActivity.DataHolder.hasData()) {
        //if hasData do your stuff what you want
        String numLocationsReported = "Text1";
        return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :) \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

    }else{
        String numLocationsReported = "Text2";
        return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :( \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

    }


}


/**
 * Returns te text for reporting about a list of  {@link Location} objects.
 *
 * @param locations List of {@link Location}s.
 */
private static String getLocationResultText(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
    if (locations.isEmpty()) {
        return "Unbekannte Position";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Location location : locations) {
        sb.append("(");
        sb.append(location.getLatitude());
        sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(location.getLongitude());
        sb.append(")");
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

static void setLocationUpdatesResult(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putString(KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_RESULT, getLocationResultTitle(context, locations)
                    + "\n" + getLocationResultText(context, locations))
            .apply();
}

static String getLocationUpdatesResult(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getString(KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_RESULT, "");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok now Your Activity looks good..

Now in **Utils class** change `if(loadAngebote.DataHolder.hasData())` to `if (AngeboteActivity.DataHolder.hasData())`

**Here:-**

```
public class Utils {
    static String getLocationResultTitle(Context context, List<Location> locations) {
        if (AngeboteActivity.DataHolder.hasData()) {
            //if hasData do your stuff what you want
            String numLocationsReported = "Text1";
            return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :) \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        } else {
            String numLocationsReported = "Text2";
            return numLocationsReported + " \r\n \r\n :( \r\n \r\n" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        }
    }
}
```